# PHP Post request returning 405 Not Allowed

Tags: php, post, request

Just started with PHP and when trying to POST request to my code it's returning 405 Not Allowed

Here's my code:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

$result = "info: ";

if( $_POST['email']) {
    $result .= $_POST['email'];
}

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: IF you get rid of all the `header()` stuff does it work?

Comment: Nope, still same.

Comment: What web server are you running

Comment: What framework do you use? Check the routes of that framework.

Comment: live server extension from vs code

Comment: That does not support PHP code. The server would need a PHP interpreter inside it and it does not. Take a look at WAMPServer or XAMPP, there are others as well

Comment: That's it, thanks! I just ran xampp and put php file into it's htdocs folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to run xampp with my php file in it's htdocs folder, thank you everyone!